# How do I prevent my query from needlessly generating rows it'll throw away later?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  stream_points.time             AS point_time,
  stream_points.value            AS point_value,
  stream_predictions.value       AS prediction_value,
  stream_predictions.upper_limit AS prediction_upper_limit,
  stream_predictions.lower_limit AS prediction_lower_limit,
  stream_anomalies.id            AS anomaly_id
FROM
  stream_points
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stream_predictions ON stream_predictions.stream_point_id = stream_points.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stream_anomalies ON stream_predictions.id = ANY (stream_anomalies.stream_prediction_ids)
WHERE
  stream_points.stream_id = 112
ORDER BY
  stream_points.time::jsonb->>'stamp' DESC;
```

with the **[following query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/BfA)**:

```
 Sort  (cost=2094370.82..2094373.84 rows=1207 width=158) (actual time=10786.273..10786.307 rows=865 loops=1)
   Sort Key: ((stream_points."time" ->> 'stamp'::text))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 253kB
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.85..2094309.04 rows=1207 width=158) (actual time=26.189..10781.366 rows=865 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (stream_predictions.id = ANY (stream_anomalies.stream_prediction_ids))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 59706594
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.85..10037.84 rows=1207 width=158) (actual time=0.017..7.435 rows=865 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using fk__stream_points_stream_id on stream_points  (cost=0.43..560.65 rows=1207 width=90) (actual time=0.010..0.761 rows=865 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (stream_id = 112)
               ->  Index Scan using index_stream_predictions_on_stream_point_id on stream_predictions  (cost=0.43..7.84 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=865)
                     Index Cond: (stream_point_id = stream_points.id)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1611.38 rows=69025 width=29) (actual time=0.002..5.323 rows=69025 loops=865)
               ->  Seq Scan on stream_anomalies  (cost=0.00..1266.25 rows=69025 width=29) (actual time=0.005..7.441 rows=69025 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.272 ms
 Execution time: 10787.335 ms
(15 rows)
```

on these tables:

```
                                     Table "public.stream_points"
   Column   |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('stream_points_id_seq'::regclass)
 stream_id  | integer                     | not null
 time       | jsonb                       | not null
 value      | jsonb                       | not null
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "stream_points_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_stream_points_on_stream_id_and_time" UNIQUE, btree (stream_id, "time")
    "fk__stream_points_stream_id" btree (stream_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_stream_points_stream_id" FOREIGN KEY (stream_id) REFERENCES streams(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "stream_predictions" CONSTRAINT "fk_stream_predictions_stream_point_id" FOREIGN KEY (stream_point_id) REFERENCES stream_points(id)

                                        Table "public.stream_predictions"
     Column      |            Type             |                            Modifiers                            
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     | not null default nextval('stream_predictions_id_seq'::regclass)
 value           | jsonb                       | 
 upper_limit     | jsonb                       | 
 lower_limit     | jsonb                       | 
 stream_point_id | integer                     | 
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "stream_predictions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_stream_predictions_on_stream_point_id" UNIQUE, btree (stream_point_id)
    "fk__stream_predictions_stream_point_id" btree (stream_point_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_stream_predictions_stream_point_id" FOREIGN KEY (stream_point_id) REFERENCES stream_points(id)

                                           Table "public.stream_anomalies"
        Column         |            Type             |                           Modifiers                           
-----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('stream_anomalies_id_seq'::regclass)
 stream_prediction_ids | integer[]                   | not null
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "stream_anomalies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_stream_anomalies_on_stream_prediction_ids" UNIQUE, btree (stream_prediction_ids)
```

It seems that a lot of data is needlessly being generated as a result of this join filter:

```
         Join Filter: (stream_predictions.id = ANY (stream_anomalies.stream_prediction_ids))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 59706594
```

and as a result the query is very slow. What can I do so that these rows are not needlessly generated?

Comment: I think the use of ` = ANY (array)` is limiting the planner's choices significantly here. I don't know whether the intarray GiST or GIN array indexes can help in joins, but I'd consider investigating that as a first step.

Comment: @CraigRinger You're probably right. I think I should amend the schema so that `stream_prediction_ids` is manifested on a join table instead.

Answer (score 1):

John, I've got a recommendation which may help significantly (I hope!)  It requires only a small change to your query, and may yield a significant performance increase.  No promises though, but test it and let me know.

## Apply unnest()

Generally speaking, I would avoid using the `ANY (array[])` syntax as [Craig Ringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7788/craig-ringer) metioned, due to the planners limited choices.  However, if the array weren't an array, but a set of records, then the planner will be much more effective.  By using `unnest()`  you can return a set of records from an array, and this has the added bonus of only parsing the array once to create the set. There is a very realisitic possibility that your array is being traversed from `stream_prediction_ids[0]` to `stream_prediction_ids[n]` for the `nth` array value.

So, on to the SQL:

```
SELECT
  stream_points.time             AS point_time,
  stream_points.value            AS point_value,
  stream_predictions.value       AS prediction_value,
  stream_predictions.upper_limit AS prediction_upper_limit,
  stream_predictions.lower_limit AS prediction_lower_limit,
  stream_anomalies.id            AS anomaly_id
FROM
  stream_points
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stream_predictions ON stream_predictions.stream_point_id = stream_points.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stream_anomalies ON stream_predictions.id IN (SELECT unnest(stream_anomalies.stream_prediction_ids))
WHERE
  stream_points.stream_id = 112
ORDER BY
  stream_points.time::jsonb->>'stamp' DESC;
```

All I did was use `IN (SELECT unnest())` rather than `= ANY()`.  Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris. However, I get a syntax error saying `syntax error on or near "unnest"`: http://pastebin.com/35FkZLCv. I'm using Postgresql 9.4.3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm certain the mistake is mine.  Let me figure out where I went wrong...

Comment: OK, sorry for the boneheaded mistake.  Have a look at the `IN (SELECT unnest())` bit. I knew I should have made a quick test script!  Syntax errors are a curse I'll never escape. :P  Anyways, try it and see if it improves the speed.  I hope it does, but no promises.  It may take a more aggressive rewriting of the query, or some minor schema changes in the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't appreciably improve things (it's actually made them about 50% worse due to the repeated subquery). Here's the new explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Wnd I think the right thing to do is just to normalize the table and not use the array of ids.

Comment: Sorry John.  I was never sure that it was going to work anyways.  Prior to altering your schema, you could simply materialize a view of the normalized version of the table using `SELECT id, unnest(stream_prediction_ids) as stream_prediction_id, created_at FROM stream_anomalies` using views/temp tables/CTEs.  This would at least let you know if altering your schema would yield benefits before making the schema change.  Of course, if the normalization helps and the `stream_anomalies` table isn't too big, you could always denormalize at query time... Sorry I couldn't be more help.